# Extrude curved surfaced by a constant distance

Tags: extrude

I'm trying to extrude an area inwards, so that the new boundary is a constant distance from the old boundary.  Essentially, the piece now has exactly the same size and shape as the hole that I have, but I want there to be a constant gap between my piece and the hole.

I've looked at [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7365/extrude-faces-along-local-normals) answer, but it doesn't give me what I want.

**Here is the original object:**

[image: Original]

**This is a sketch of what I want:**

[image: What I want]

**Here's what I have tried:**

Extrude region:

[image: Extrude region - not what I want]

Extrude region (vertex normals):

[image: Extrude region vertex normals - not what I want either]

Extrude individual:

[image: Extrude individual - also not what I want]

How can I get what I want?

[Here is my file.](http://btzy.github.io/extrude-not-working.blend)

Thanks!

**EDIT**: Here is what happens if I use the solidify modifier:

[image: Solidify modifier settings]

It sort of works, but the distance between the new wall and the old one isn't uniform.  This is how it looks like (the distances highlighted in red should be uniform, but they aren't):

[image: Solidify modifier outcome]

Comment: Did you try using solidify modifier?

Comment: Solidify modifier sort of does it, but distance from the original walls aren't very uniform (see my edit).  If there's no better way then I suppose this would have to do.  Pardon my lack of skills, I'm new to Blender.

Comment: If you apply the scale of the object that should fix the thickness.

Comment: How did you design that shape? Was it ever a bezier curve through the course of its existence? It looks like this would be far easier and more suited to do this with a *Bezier Curve*. They have an *Offset* property which allows doing exactly what you want to achieve. Also *Extrude Region by Vertex Normals* should do what you want, just a matter of controlling the direction correctly

Comment: It was designed using cylinders and planes.  All the "curved" surfaces are arcs that have exactly 2cm radius.

Comment: @Denis could you please elaborate what you mean by "apply the scale of the object"?  I don't see a "scale" option in the solidify modifier.

Comment: In Object mode, Ctrl+A and choose scale. Denis's combined comments solves your problem.

Comment: @cmomoney  Thank you!  I still don't know what "apply the object's transformation to its data" means, but it works!

Comment: Transformations done in Object mode are not directly applied to the mesh data. Your just basically transforming the "container" of the data.

Comment: please attach the file and you will get the solution soon

Answer (score 1):

See Properties (N) > Transform > Scale XYZ is not 1 in all axis.
Since Modifier transformation is applied first on Object Data and Object Transformation after means Solidifier extrudes thickness and Object Transform squeeze that result.

[image]

To solve your issue Apply Scale Transformation (Ctrl+A)

[image]

What Object Transform is see [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64591/what-is-the-exact-purpose-of-object-scale?answertab=votes#tab-top) or check [Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/transforms.html).