# Unexpected result of very simple uv unwrap

Tags: uv-image-editor

Why would a cuboid with seams as shown unwrap as a cube? I eventually found one tutorial example of a cuboid rather than a cube being unwrapped. Its result as illustrated in the article was as expected but in 20 attempts I could only reproduce it once. All the other attempts with different seams, different unwraps, renders etc produced a cube's unwrap.

[image]

Comment: My guess is that you scaled a cube to a cuboid in object mode without applying the scale. Try hitting `Ctrl` `A` followed by `S` in object mode, and see if that helps.

Comment: What is the exact purpose of object scale?: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/64598/7777

Comment: Yes, thank you, I had not applied the scale.  Now into hours of diversion to understand another accidentally discovered fundamental.